# WPF Resource Dictionary using code behind file can’t be found

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

When I include an assembly containing a ResourceDictionary using the following pack syntax:

```
"pack://application:,,,/WpfCore;component/ResourceDictionaries/ThemedControls.xaml"
```

It works as expected, but as soon as I add a code behind file to the XAML of the ResourceDictionary, the following error is thrown:
“An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary”

The code behind is added to the XAML in the usual way:

```
< ResourceDictionary x:Class="com.mycompany.WpfCore.ResourceDictionaries.ThemedControls"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and looks like this:

```
namespace com.mycompany.WpfCore.ResourceDictionaries
{
    public partial class ThemedControls : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public ThemedControls ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Intuition tells me this is a namespace problem, but all the variations I've tried fail. What am I doing wrong or is this a limitation of WPF ResourceDictionaries?

**Edit**:

Seems the question detail was called out and found to be wanting.

The initial example had the namespace simplified. The default namespace for the WpfCore project is *com.mycompany.WpfCore* which I have now added into the code examples above.

The ThemedControls.xaml and ThemedControls.xaml.cs files are located in a subfolder called ResourceDictionaries within the WpfCore project folder.
The resulting assembly is used as a referenced assembly in another solution and this is where the Pack URI is being used.

**Edit 2**:

After playing around with the build action for the xaml files (changing from page to resource and back again) things started working. Marking Sheridan's answer as correct.

Comment: Why are you adding a code-behind file to ResourceDictionary?

Comment: The code behind merges additional dictionaries based on runtime system information, i.e. different resource dictionaries for different OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you have declared your `ResourceDictionary` quite correctly... the application name really should be in the namespace. This *should* work... at least it works for me:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="WpfCore.ResourceDictionaries.ThemedControls">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace WpfCore.ResourceDictionaries
{
    public partial class ThemedControls : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public ThemedControls()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems this will work within the same solution, which is not exactly how I am doing it. The question may have been a little vague and has been updated with more detail about using the assembly as a referenced assembly.

Comment: Ah, sorry but I haven't experienced that situation yet, so I can't help any further.